# Highchart loses fillOpacity when fillColor is specified

Tags: highcharts

When I set this:

```
series: {
fillOpacity: 0.5,
fillColor:'#fff000'
}
```

highcharts will ignore opacity, if I take away fillcolor, the opacity works. However, I was asked to set fillcolour to be different.

http://jsfiddle.net/ywL646r8/1/. Can someone help?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set the fill color with a rgba value

```
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            color: '#ff0000',
        },
        series: {
            fillColor:'rgba(255,240,0,.5)'
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ywL646r8/2/

Comment: great. Works perfectly!